# Given $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $8x^3 - 4x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0$. Find all rationals $p, q, r$ such that $px + q(2x^2 - 1) + r(4x^3 - 3x) = -4$.

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots, cubics

> Given $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $8x^3 - 4x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0$. Find all rationals $p, q, r$ such that $$\large px + q(2x^2 - 1) + r(4x^3 - 3x) = -4$$

We have that $$8x^3 - 4x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0 \iff (-1) + 2x - 2 \cdot (2x^2 - 1) + 2 \cdot (4x^3 - 3x) = 0$$ and $$px + q(2x^2 - 1) + r(4x^3 - 3x) = -4 \iff (-4) \cdot (-1) + px + q(2x^2 - 1) + r(4x^3 - 3x) = 0$$

This implies that $(p + 8)x + (q - 8)(2x^2 - 1) + (r + 8)(4x^3 - 3x) = 0$.

One solution is that $p + 8 = q - 8 = r + 8 = 0 \implies (p, q, r) = (-8, 8, -8)$

I suspect to there be other solutions of $(p, q, r)$, for example, $$x = \frac{1}{6} \cdot \left[1 - \sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}(3\sqrt3i + 1)} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}(3\sqrt3i - 1)}\right]$$, according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8x%5E3%20-%204x%5E2%20-%204x%20%2B%201%20%3D%200), is a solution to the equation $8x^3 - 4x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0$.

Right... So WolframAlpha is untrustworthy, according to [Michael Rozenberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3503008/given-x-in-mathbb-r-such-that-8x3-4x2-4x-1-0-find-all-rationals/3503025?noredirect=1#comment7204584_3503025), the solutions to $8x^3 - 4x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0$ are $\cos\dfrac{\pi}{7}, \cos\dfrac{3\pi}{7}, \cos\dfrac{5\pi}{7}$, which is correct when plugged into the original equation.

Comment: Question: Since the equation has 3 real roots, a choice for $(p,q,r)$ has to work for all the roots? Or can we have different $(p,q,r)$ for the different roots?

Comment: Well, we could have $(p, q, r)$ for different roots.

Comment: But the question is whether a fixed choice for $(p,q,r)$ has to work for all $x=x_1,x_2,x_3$ or just for one of those? In other words, do we have a system of 3 equations?

Comment: Now that I think about it, yes, we have a system of 3 equations. The problem would have infinitely many solutions if the condition above isn't achieved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$8x^3 - 4x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0$ and  $4rx^3+2qx^2+(p-3r)x+(4-q)=0$.

**Case 1**
If the original cubic is irreducible over the rationals then the coefficients of the various powers of $x$ in the two cubics must be in proportion. (Otherwise, one or more roots would satisfy a rational polynomial of degree less than $3$ obtained as a linear combination of the two cubics.) Then 
$$4r=8t, 2q=-4t,p-3=-4t,4-q=t.$$
This gives the solution $p=-8,q=8,r=-8.$

**Case 2**
Otherwise the cubic has a rational root $\frac{a}{b}$ with $(a,b)=1$ and so 
$$8a^3-4a^2b-4ab^2+b^3=0$$ Then $a$ divides $b^3$ and so $a=1$. Then $b$ would have to be $\pm2$ but these do not satisfy the equation and so there are **no** further solutions.

Comment: +1 for the elementary solution. As a suggestion, you could add why irreducible $\implies$ proportional.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Define $g(x) = 8x^3 - 4x^2 - 4x + 1$ and 
$$\begin{align}h(x) &=  px + q(2x^2 - 1) + r(4x^3 - 3x) +4\\
 &= 4rx^3 + 2qx^2 + (p-3r)x + (4-q).\end{align}$$

In other terms, your question is: for what $p,q,r$ does $h(\alpha) = 0$, for every $\alpha: g(\alpha)=0$?

Well, $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed, so $g(x)$ has $3$ (not necessarily distinct) roots; let $\alpha$ be one of them. Let's take a look at its derivative: $g'(x)= 24x^2-8x - 4$. If $\alpha$ has multiplicity greater than $1$, then we know that $g'(\alpha) = 0$. [By polynomial long division](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpIBL.jpg), we have that $g(x) = d(x)g'(x) + (-\frac{28}{9}x+\frac79)$. So, if $\alpha$ has  multiplicity greater than $1$,

$$\overbrace{g(\alpha)}^0 = d(\alpha)\underbrace{g'(\alpha)}_0 + \frac19(-28\alpha + 7) = \frac19(-28\alpha+ 7).$$

So $\alpha = \frac{7}{28} = \frac14$. But [$g(\frac14) = -\frac{1}{8}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=evaluate+8x%5E3+-+4x%5E2+-++4x+%2B++1++at+x+%3D+1%2F4), so no root has multiplicity greater than one. Thus we have $3$ distinct roots $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$ to both $g$ and $h$. To prove that your result is the only possible, we'll use a trick to have a polynomial identity: define

$$\begin{align}
l(x) &= rg(x) - 2h(x)\\
&= (-4r-4q)x^2 + (2r-2p)x + (r-8+2q).\\
\end{align}$$

Note that $\operatorname{deg}l\leq 2$. Also, $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$ are roots. But the number of roots certainly exceeds the degree of this polynomial, so it must be **identical to $0$**, i.e., all coefficients are $0$. Finally,
$$
\begin{cases}
-4r -4q &= 0\\
2r  -2p &= 0\\
r+2q-8 &= 0
\end{cases} \,\,\therefore \boxed{(p,q,r) = (-8,8,-8).}$$

You can check this linear system [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20linear%20system&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation1%22%7D%20-%3E%22-4r%20-%204q%20%3D%200%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22solve%20linear%20system%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation2%22%7D%20-%3E%222r%20-%202p%20%3D%200%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation3%22%7D%20-%3E%22r%2B2q-8%20%3D%200%22), and it guarantees uniqueness.

Comment: Did you mean $\alpha=7/28=1/4$ when checking for multiplicity?
Another way to confirm there are three distinct real roots is to reduce the equation to the form $t^3+pt+q$ using $x=t+1/6$ and check that $p^3/27+q^2/4<0$.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks.